# In mac mini not able to login in xamarin IDE

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I just updated my xamarin  IDE,while i'm trying to restore solution nuget packages are not restoring ,i tried login in xamarin it shows "please connect to network to proceed ",I've good internet connection and able to brows but xamarin IDE not able to communicate with servers Can any one help to resolve this Xamarin IDE issue?

Comment: Is there a proxy involved? Xamarin Studio should be fine with most proxies, but it's a possible issue.

Comment: See if this issue is related to your problem: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=40823